# DataTable shows zero rows even get the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable.I tried to load via ajax .The response contain data but it shows no data found.My code is given below

```
<table  id="user_list_table"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>    
        <th>name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>address</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My js contains

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var MY_AJAX_ACTION_URL = "/social/index.php?id=4&userform[action]=datatable&userform[controller]=User";
     $('#user_list_table').dataTable({
            "autoWidth": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "oLanguage": {
              "sZeroRecords": "No data Found",
              "sProcessing": 'processing'
            },
            "bInfo": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                {'mData':'name','bSortable': true},
                {'mData':'phone','bSortable': true},
                { 'mData':'email','bSortable': true },
                { 'mData':'address','bSortable': true}
            ],
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource":MY_AJAX_ACTION_URL
        });

});
```

I got the following response

```
 {"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":{"data":[{"name":"xyz","phone":"678654454","email":"xyz@gmail.com","address":"ytruye"},{"name":"abc","phone":"678654454","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":"ytruye"}]}}
```

Comment: Is your table showing any error or "No data Found" ?

Comment: It is not error.. I wrote the message when the table contain zero record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server response is a little bit missed up. You have

```
{
  "iTotalRecords": 2,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": {
    "data": [
```

but `iTotalDisplayRecords` is supposed to be the *number* of filtered records (and `iTotalRecords` of course the total number of records). If you correct the response to

```
{
  "iTotalRecords": 2,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
  "data": [
    {
```

and remove `"sAjaxDataProp": "",` then it works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2o6eLt2z/**

So the problem is serverside, there is no possible way to correct the problem clientside since the JSON will never work with dataTables as a serverside source. You could use the serverscript in an `ajax: { url: ...}` and return the corrected JSON in the `dataSrc` callback, but it seems to me you want to use serverside processing.